# Wrapping calls to method on a class with a standard try/catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception, delegates

I have a class that has about 200+ methods, each of these methods makes a call into the database, or a network resource.

Ideally, I would like to wrap each call in a try/catch, to catch any of the common network or SQL exceptions, and give the user the opportunity to try again (if appropriate). However, to add this code to each call would be very time consuming, and bloated as far as the code is concerned.

I've thought about wrapping each of the method calls in another method, creating a delegate, and wrapping the delegate code in the try/catch.. something like this...

**(Ignore the syntax.. it's just a conceptual example)**

```
bool CallUpdatePassenger(int PassengerId,string PassengerName,string PhoneNumber)
{
    Delegate del= Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UpdatePassengerDelegate), typeof(IPassengerServices).GetMethod("RemoteUpdatePassenger"));
    bool Res=(bool)CallDelegate(del,PassengerName,PhoneNumber);
}
object CallDelegate(Delegate del,params object[] args)
{
    object Result=null;
    try
    {
        Result=del.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
    catch (Some.Timeout.Error.Or.Whatever te)
    {
        // take some action.. maybe retry etc.. 
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Maybe there's a more pracitcal way of doing this ?

The code is automatically generated (by a tool which I wrote) I can quite easily include something like the above, but I want to avoid writing the above code for every method call.

Also, if I do something like the above, I can time methods, and log method calls etc. It just seems a bit clumsy (and not strongly typed).

Thanks
Rich.

Comment: The underlying problem, of course, is that you have spread your DB access code over 200 methods instead of calling one method from those 200 methods that handles the DB access as well as exceptions for you.

Comment: have you looked into using attributes yet?

Comment: @mtijn unless you are using PostSharp, attributes don't actively participate - and are inert

Comment: codesparkle, if there was one method, it couldn't be strongly typed, I like the idea of calling a method with a set list of strongly typed parameters based on the actual call. I guess I could have a 'client-side' method which accepts the correct parameters, builds a structure representing the DB call (or maybe serialize the SqlCommand - including parameters) pass this into a standard method on the server, which unwraps it and tries to call.. I could do my try/catching on the client side after building the SqlCommand.

Comment: @mtijn, no, I've not looked into attributes, can you elaborate ?

Comment: If you made use of Marc's answer, you could also use attributes if you needed to vary what you did slightly for different methods.  For example, you could create a custom attribute to say what you wanted the timeout to be for each method, apply that attribute to each of the methods and then check for the attribute inside Execute.

Comment: @Tuskan the lambda will be a delegate to a compiler-generated method, not the final method - so obtaining attributes will not be trivial. Using Expression could make that possible but us complex too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should be able to just do something like:

```
T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) {
    try {
        return func();
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
bool CallUpdatePassenger(some args here) {
    return Execute( () => realObj.RemoteUpdatePassenger(some args here));
}
```

alternatively, you could use meta-programming to write a dynamic "decorator" for the underlying methods on the fly... but unless you are familiar with `ILGenerator` etc probably best not to - it is a fairly advanced topic.

Comment: +1, but in this case, imo, if you need some behavior diversity based on in *what* function exception was thrown, the decorator or `ILGenerator` fits better. Unless you not decide to define different `Execute<T>` methods for different behavior patterns.

Comment: @Tigran the comparison here, though, is primarily to the awkward `DynamicInvoke` example in the question

Comment: @MarcGravell - thanks for this.. but would I not need a separate block of code for every set of possible paramters ? I think I need to read up on Lambda expressions.. I've seen quite a bit of them recently.

Comment: @Rich no; that is handled by the lambda and capture

Comment: @MarcGravell The suggestion posted by ckarras below seems very similar (in usage terms) to your suggestion, is there any benifit of either solution ? both seem good !!

Comment: @Rich it is a pain to get the rerun value from `Action` (although can be done). But not everything *has* a return value! Frankly you could use both - maybe `ExecuteQuery<T>(Func<T>)` and `ExcuteNonQuery(Action)`

Comment: #marc & @ckarras  - I'm looking at both of your solutions, and I've tried implementing #Marc's first. My concerns about the above solution, is that at compile time (AFAICT), it will expand out the method for each call anyway, which would create quite a large dll. Also, after implementing, it is complaining that 'the arguments can't be inferred from the usage' for the methods that have no return value. Does #ckarras's suggestion avoid the 'bloating' of the dll, and also is there a way of getting around the lack of return value. Thanks, Rich.

Comment: @RichS the Action instead of func means it doesn't need a return value. Re "expanding it out" - not really: it *does* create an additional hidden method per lambda, but that really isn't large - and is identical between Action and Func. Of course, it depends a bit on what you mean by "bloating". Btw, you can spoof a return value; `() => { SomeMethodCall(); return true; }`. I"d prefer the option of having two methods - one witha Func, one with an Action.  No spoofing, then.

Answer (score 13):

I think your basic idea is good, but there's a simpler way to implement it (at least of you're using .Net 3.5 or more recent):

```
void WithStandardRetryLogic(Action method) 
{
    try
    {
        method();
    }
    catch (Some.Timeout.Error.Or.Whatever te)     
    {         
        // take some action.. maybe retry etc..      
    } 
}
```

Example use:

```
WithStandardRetryLogic(delegate() { CallUpdatePassenger(PassengerId, PassengerName, PhoneNumber); });
```

This may also be something where an AOP framework might be useful, but I have not tried that solution.

Comment: This is very nice. Its the easiest way of wrapping methods that I've seen for folks not familiar with delegates and such.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use PostSharp, you can use this aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class RetryAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private readonly int _times;

    public RetryAttribute(int times)
    {
        _times = times;
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        for (var left = _times; left > 0; left--)
        {
            try
            {
                args.Proceed();
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        args.Proceed(); // optional
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
[Retry(2)]
public static void DoIt()
{
    Console.WriteLine("tried");
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, this is the Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the possible solutions can be [AOP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-i/) programming. You can mark any method you want with an attribute and inject the `try/catch` code on compilation.

See a sample [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Introduction-to-Aspect-Oriented-Programming-and-PostSharp.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very interesting.. I've heard a few 'rumours' about AOP, I will have a butchers.. thanks.